# Passing Data from Android Notifications

Tags: android, notifications

I have built a notification and am displaying it properly, but I can't figure out how to pass data to the activity. I pulled one string from the intent to display as the title of the notification, but I need to pull a 2nd string, and have the NotificationHandlerActivity process it.

//inside intentservice

```
private void sendNotification(Bundle extras) {
    Intent intent=new Intent(this, NotificationHandlerActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.putExtra("link", extras.getString("link"));
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
    long[] vibrate = {100L, 75L, 50L};
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.abc_ic_menu_copy_mtrl_am_alpha)
                    .setContentTitle(extras.getString("title"))
                    .setOngoing(false)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setVibrate(vibrate);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
}
```

//Inside NotificationHandlerActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
}
```

Comment: see my answer below. it explains what is going on more than the other two; also, I was the one who up'd you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently using 0 as the requestCode when calling getActivity() on the PendingIntent isn't the way to go. I updated it to just use System.currentTimeMillis() and that seemed to work. I'm assuming that the first time I built the notification, using 0 as the requestCode, the extra wasn't present.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the extras on your Intent. Because your intent is currently anonymous, you cannot do so. Extras are basic key-value stores. See below:

```
public static final String KEY_SECOND_STRING = "keySecondString";
...

    ...
    String secondString = "secondString";
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)     
         this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationHandlerActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(KEY_SECOND_STRING, secondString);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
    ...
```

then, from your NotificationHandlerActivity, you can access that secondString from the intent.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle sIS){
    super.onCreate();
    String secondString = getIntent().getStringExtra("keySecondString");
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use it like this :

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this, NotificationHandlerActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("key", "value");

mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
long[] vibrate = {100L, 75L, 50L};
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.abc_ic_menu_copy_mtrl_am_alpha)
                .setContentTitle(extras.getString("title")) 
                .setOngoing(false) 
                .setAutoCancel(true) 
                .setVibrate(vibrate);
mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```